# Casting tableViewCell as UIPickerView exactly how it is done with UIDatePicker for inline date picker not working

Tags: ios

I am attempting to use an inline PickerView in my application, and it works fine except for one thing. when I try to set the row of the picker to a specific row based on a data argument my application crashes.

```
 UITableViewCell *associatedTypePickerCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.datePickerIndexPath];
        UIPickerView *targetedPickerView = (UIPickerView *)[associatedTypePickerCell viewWithTag:kTypePickerTag];
        if (targetedPickerView != nil){
            NSLog(@"type picker ! = nil");
            NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[self.datePickerIndexPath.row-1];
            Type *type = [itemData valueForKey:kDateKey];
            NSInteger row = [[self types] indexOfObject:type];
            [targetedPickerView selectRow:row inComponent:0 animated:NO];
        }
```

I am getting this error:

```
-[UITableViewCell selectRow:inComponent:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ecba70
2014-07-22 23:47:23.384 MyGIJournal[16636:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell selectRow:inComponent:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ecba70'
```

does anyone know why this is crashing? it seems like casting like this to a UIPickerView isn't working, which doesn't make much sense cause this is the exact same way I do it for the UIDatePicker and it worked for that... Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `kTypePickerTag`?

Comment: the value of kTypePickerTag is set to 3, because I have 3 different types of pickers

Comment: Are your cells tagged? If the cell also has a tag value of 3 then that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: which one should have the tag?

Comment: Tag the view you need to search for - the picker view.